# Sublime3 creating empty file Plain Text or Textfile?

Tags: sublimetext3

I Installed Sublime Text 3 and I'm trying to create an empty file ".txt", from the bottom right menu to choose "Plain Text" or "Textfile", I want to create an empty file writing normal text, which one is the correct to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad the file type is called "textile" not "textfile", I think plain text is the correct answer.

> Plain text, Plain-text, or Plaintext is any text, text file, or
>   document that contains only text. ... Most associate plain text files
>   with the file extension . txt on Microsoft Windows computers, however,
>   can be any non-formatted file. To view a plaintext file, a text editor
>   such as Microsoft Notepad is used.

Comment: `Plain text` is indeed the file type you want for a generic text file. Note however that it's also the default file type in Sublime, so any tab you create is automatically the correct type.